# Can't detect huge memory usage in C program

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I am experiencing a huge memory usage when running my C program. It uses way more memory than it is expected to use. Even the OS sometimes has to kill the process due to a lot of memory usage (And I have 20GB of RAM in my machine). I try to run valgrind to see if there are some clues about what is going on with memory usage. Among the valgrind output, I can see a warning that might be pointing to the issue:

```
==69541== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x76eb040, 0x2cb27240) (undefined)
```

However, I do not know how to know where is this large range of memory being allocated.

Hope this is not a too generic question. I tried to provide the minimum details to solve the issue, but if needed, I can provide more information.

Comment: It could be a memory leak.  Are you using malloc?  Also are there any recursive function calls or any arrays that may be very large?

Comment: Yes, it's a big project with lots of memory allocations. Could it be possible to detect the `malloc`(s) associated to this large range?

Comment: Valgrind memcheck should be able to detect memory leaks.  You will need to make sure that any variables used to store pointers that point to objects created with malloc are deallocated using free before they fall out of scope or are reassigned.

Comment: Thanks for your point, I will take a look back to the code and try to find mallocs without frees. However, is there a way that valgrind or some other utility might point me to the line of code where this huge mem allocation happens?

Comment: Valgrind memcheck should tell you if a memory leak is the problem, but I don’t think it can identify specifically where.  There may be a static analysis tool that can identify where, but it may depend on the complexity of the program.

Comment: Indeed it's a quite complex program. Could you recommend some of these tools to take a look to them?

Comment: You will want a good static analysis tool.  There are several on the market, but they generally cost have to be purchased.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the problem. I post here the approach I used and worked for me, just in case it might be useful for someone else (although probably is not the neatest one).

Using the debugger I spotted the place were the huge allocation was taking place (it was taking a lot of time). Then I realized that I was creating a hash-table object, which its size is passed as parameter. I was not passing the parameter, so the program was taking a garbage (big) number as the size.

Thanks to all of you that shared your thoughts about my question :)

Comment: Your compiler should warn you if you call a function incorrectly - but that supposes you've declared the prototype for it before hand - which is also something worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Valgrind with **--leak-check=full** option and compile code with **-g** option

Example:

```
cat my_leak.c ; gcc -g my_leak.c ; valgrind --leak-check=full a.out
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
    char* a = malloc(1000000);
    return 0;
}
==29805== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29805== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29805== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29805== Command: a.out
==29805== 
==29805== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
==29805== 
==29805== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29805==     in use at exit: 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==29805==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1,000,000 bytes allocated
==29805== 
==29805== 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==29805==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29805==    by 0x10915E: main (my_leak.c:4)
==29805== 
==29805== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29805==    definitely lost: 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==29805==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29805==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29805==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29805==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29805== 
==29805== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==29805== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Valgrind version:

```
valgrind --version
valgrind-3.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The message that you copied is generated whenever Valgrind sets permissions on a new range of memory that is larger than 256Mbytes. Such large allocations are somewhat suspicious and could be an error in the calculation of the memory size.

In your case the allocation is 625197568 bytes (about 596Mbytes).

You can use the `massif` tool to see where this is being allocated (or a non-Valgrind tool like heaptrack).

Comment: Using `massif` (i.e. running `valgrind --tool=masif`) I can't get the large allocation warning I was getting before.

Comment: Does it run to completion? If so you need to either run `ms_print` (in the valgrind bin directory) or, if you can get it, a separate viewer, `massif-visualizer`.